# No Errror But Android App Crashing due to SetContentView

Tags: android

Hey Guys Please Help Me identify the problem...Its indicates that SetContentView is Not Set Well.What Do I Have To Do Guys...

Main Activity

```
    package com.example.freddie.ukulimamachinery;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH=5000;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar !=null)
        {
          actionBar.hide();
        }
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent startActivityIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(startActivityIntent);
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        },SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
    }

    }
```

activity_main

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/_16sdp"
    tools:context="com.example.freddie.ukulimamachinery.LoginActivity">



</RelativLayout>
```

LoginActivity

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/_16sdp"
    tools:context="com.example.freddie.ukulimamachinery.LoginActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ukulima"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/login_error"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/no_text"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_56sdp"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:hint="@string/email_hint"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_border"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_error"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:hint="@string/password_hint"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_border"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:layout_below="@+id/email"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login_button"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/password"
                android:text="@string/login_button"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_16sdp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_24sdp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="@string/sign_up"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat shows These

```
    ukulimamachinery/com.example.freddie.ukulimamachinery.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class RelativLayout
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
                                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class RelativLayout
                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                             at com.example.freddie.ukulimamachinery.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
                                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825) 
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641) 
                                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.RelativLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.freddie.ukulimamachinery-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.freddie.ukulimamachinery-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                             at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                                                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 
                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                             at com.example.freddie.ukulimamachinery.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23) 
                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264) 
                                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302) 
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825) 
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641) 
                                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
09-28 13:43:08.328 31955-31955/com.example.freddie.ukulimamachinery E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: com.example.freddie.ukulimamachinery, PID: 31955
                                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.freddie.ukulimamachinery/com.example.freddie.ukulimamachinery.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class RelativLayout
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
                                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class RelativLayout
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                          at com.example.freddie.ukulimamachinery.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
                                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641) 
                                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.RelativLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.freddie.ukulimamachinery-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.freddie.ukulimamachinery-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                          at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                                                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                          at com.example.freddie.ukulimamachinery.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23) 
                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264) 
                                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

This Error Mainly appears due To the SetContentView with indication of OnCreate Option yet in my activity_main I have Set it reliance on the LoginActivity Page

Answer (score 5):

activity_main.xml: RelativLayout instead of RelativeLayout (letter E at the end of word Relative missing)

Answer (score 0):

try this use **RelativeLayout** insted of **RelativLayout**

just change your  activity_main.xml:  like below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/_16sdp"
    tools:context="com.example.freddie.ukulimamachinery.LoginActivity">



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your activity main change :

```
<RelativLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> ...
```

to :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace **RelativLayout** with **RelativeLayout** in activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/_16sdp"
    tools:context="com.example.freddie.ukulimamachinery.LoginActivity">
</RelativLayout>
```

Comment: can u guys check the last code after correcting the syntax error because it seems that still my login Activity is crashing